# how to refresh a combobox when submiting a query through another combobox?

Tags: php, html

Actually i want to update a combobox on submiting a query through another combobox.
So what i have to do ?
any idea ?
i am using html and php.

Comment: what you mean **on submiting a query through**

Comment: I mean i submit a value like "2010" throgh a combobox then i want to add all the student name in another combobox(by fetching from database) who passed in 2010.My main aim is to refresh the next combobox after submiting the value from another combobox.

Answer (score 0):

On the `select` element you have to use the `onChange` event and trigger the function that will fill the other `select`

Answer (score 0):

select box 1

```
<select name="list1" id="list1">
 <option value="">select</option> 
<option value="1">option1</option>
 <option value="2">option2</option> 
<option value="3">option3</option> 
</select>
```

your dynamic combo

```
<div id="ajax_input">
<select name="list2" id="list2">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>
</div>
```

script

```
$('#list1').change(function(){

var value  = $(this).val();

$("#ajax_input").load("serverpage.php?value="+value); 

});
```

you can generate your dynamic select box on

> serverpage.php

this will work in

`onchange`

event not in submit